# Can I recover from partial install?

Tags: system-installation

Using 14.04.  I sought the upgrade option from Ubuntu.  It proceeded, seemingly without problem.  Difficulty came when installing fonts!  "Config TTF msconfig installer."  The machine would not respond to the "OK" prompt.  I bailed out after 10 minutes.  Reboot has produced something, but it is non-graphical and the water is a tad deep for me.
I have an install disk for 16.04.  I hope to recover using that medium for repair, else a full fresh install.
Can anyone give me pointers about the terminal commands I need?
Thanks in advance.